# Parse XML with XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt

With XSLT 1.0, I would like to remove all nodes tagged node if they have no children with the attribute right-value, left-value or value.

The initial file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node>
    <left-node key="Network0">
        <node key="@FR" value="tom"/>
    </left-node>
    <node key="Network1">
       <node key="PortNumber" left-value="12000" right-value="12001"/>
       <node key="Location"/>
    </node>
    <node key="Network2">
        <node key="PortNumber" left-value="12000" right-value="12001"/>
        <node key="Location">
            <node key="Office" left-value="IT" right-value="HR"/>
            <right-node key="GO" value="Yellow"/>
        </node>
        <right-node key="Try"/>
    </node>
    <node key="Network3">
        <node key="Location">
             <node key="Hardware"/>
             <node key="Software"/>
        </node>
    </node>
    <right-node key="Network4">
        <node key="@GB" value="tim"/>
    </right-node>
</node>
```

With the example, I would like to get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<node> 
    <left-node key="Network0">
        <node key="@FR" value="tom"/>
    </left-node>
    <node key="Network1">
       <node key="PortNumber" left-value="12000" right-value="12001"/>
    </node>
    <node key="Network2">
        <node key="PortNumber" left-value="12000" right-value="12001"/>
        <node key="Location">
            <node key="Office" left-value="IT" right-value="HR"/>
            <right-node key="GO" value="Yellow"/>
        </node>
        <right-node key="Try"/>
    </node>
    <right-node key="Network4">
        <node key="@GB" value="tim"/>
    </right-node>
</node>
```

I am able to get the nodes tagged left-node or right-node but for the nodes tagged node I have problems.

```
`<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node[not(@value!='' or @right-value!='' or @left-value!='') ]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>`
```

Comment: Why is the `<right-node key="Try"/>` in your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `descendant-or-self` axis.
So use this excluding template:

```
<xsl:template match="node[not(descendant-or-self::*[@right-value or @left-value or @value])]" />
```

The output should be as desired.